# Summability of a function through the absolute convergence of a series

Tags: integration, measure-theory, summation, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of real numbers and let $f:[1,+\infty)\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=\sum_na_n\chi_{[n,n+1)}(x)$.
I have to show that $f$ is summable iff $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent.
This is what I've tried (I'm new with Lebesgue's theory and I'd like to know if I'm doing exercises correctly): Let $f_n(x)=a_n\chi_{[n,n+1)}(x)$, then $f(x)=\sum_n f_n(x)$. I know that $f$ is summable iff $\int_{[1,+\infty)}|f|<\infty$, but
$$\int_1^{+\infty}|f|dx=\int_1^{+\infty}\Big|\sum_nf_n\Big|dx\le\int_1^{+\infty}\sum_n|f_n|dx=\int_1^{+\infty}\sum_n\underbrace{|a_n\chi_{[n,n+1)}(x)|}_{\ge 0}dx=$$$$=\sum_n\int_1^{+\infty}|a_n\chi_{[n,n+1)}(x)|dx=$$
$$=\sum_n\int_n^{n+1}|a_n|dx=\sum_n|a_n|$$
so I think that this shows that $\int f<\infty\iff\sum_n|a_n|<\infty$ and in the same way (?) we can show that $\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_1^{b}f$ exists and it is finite iff $\sum_na_n$ is convergent.

Comment: What does $f$ summable mean? Do you mean integrable with respect to the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: I mean that $\int f^+$ and $\int f^-$ exist and they are  both finite (summable implies integrable)

Comment: You have $\leq $ in your argument. You cannot draw the final conclusion from this.

Comment: So if $\sum a_n<\infty\implies f$ is summable. I've showed the direction from right to left (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument needs the following change: Since only one term in $\sum f_n$ is non-zero at any point $x$ it folows that $|\sum f_n(x)|=\sum |f_n(x)|$ for all $x$. Now you can replace the inequality in your proof by an equality. The proof is now complete.